# Python: Removing a specific item that has a duplicate only knowing its index in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

What I want this program to do is to delete all the 1's that are in the list that follow by index all the 2's.

This is the code:

```
a = [3, 1, 2, 1]
a.remove(a[3])
print(a)
```

I really put this program into the basics but the point is that I have only got the index of the 1 that follows the 2, tho when I do this the result is:

```
[3, 2, 1]
```

This means that it doesn't delete the 1 I want but just the first 1 it finds. Tho this is really a problem in a real program situation where the first 1 is an important value.

How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: It's almost like you saying you want your list to have only one occurrence of each element. Is that correct?

Comment: Are you asking how to remove all `1`s form a list if the `1` follows a `2`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
a = [3, 1, 2, 1]
new_a = [c for i, c in enumerate(a) if c != 1 and i+1 < len(a) and a[i+1] != 2]+[a[-1]]
```

Output:

```
[3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a *good-ol'* explicit loop for this one:

```
a = [3, 1, 2, 1]
b = [a[0]]

for i, item in enumerate(a[1:], 1):
  if item == 1 and a[i-1] == 2:
    continue
  else:
    b.append(item)
print(b)  # -> [3, 1, 2]
```

---

Note that `a` does not get modified but rather a new list `b` is created.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a specific index you use `del`.

```
a = [3, 1, 2, 1]
del a[3]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: He's looking to remove only the '1's following '2's, so he may not necessarily know the index before runtime.

Comment: From my interpretation of his question he is struggling to delete points at specified indexes. Which is then to be used to remove 1 following a 2.

Answer (score 0):

The `del` keyword might be your best bet here, for example:

```
a = [3, 1, 2, 1]
index = 1
while index < len(a):
    if a[index - 1] == 2 and a[index] == 1:
        del a[index]
    else:
        index += 1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the more pythonic way to do this, but you can keep a counter to check for the second appearance of a value you want to delete from a list.

```
a = [3, 1, 2, 1]
counter = 0

for i, v in enumerate(a):
    if v==1:
        if counter == 1:
            del a[i]
        else:
            counter += 1

print a

#output: [3, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension with `enumerate(a)` and `index(2)`

```
[j for i,j in enumerate(a) if not (i>a.index(2) and j==1)]
#[3, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [3, 1, 2, 1]
>>> [v for i, v in enumerate(a) if not i or not (v == 1 and a[i-1] == 2)]
[3, 1, 2]
```